# On screen Navigation Keys

Tags: windows-10-mobile, buttons, touch

I am using a Nokia Lumia 720. For the past couple of months the capacitive navigation keys are giving me trouble ie they are not working. I wanted to know if there is any possibility of getting on screen navigation keys just like Lumia 530 or any other phone that does not have an explicit navigation button.

Note: I am using a windows phone 10 insider preview.

Comment: use a bluetooth mouse with home button

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately at this point you cannot get the phone to show the navigation keys if it has hardware keys build in.

I'd recommend submitting your idea through the Feedback app, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can have virtual navigation bar on your phone if you don't mind unlocking it. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-VxgdGcaBjs) is a video where you can have step by step instructions throughout the process. Though video does not provide you links for interop tools and SDK you can download them from below links.

Interop Tools: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzsmZaCgRWvycHlLRktXYzhSNXc

SDK: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive

Cheers!